# Java GUI - changing timer pause to keyboard prompt

Tags: java, time, keyboard, intervals, prompt

I have a program which creates a window, loops through an array of colours and changes the window background to these colours.

I have used a pause method to allow me to pause each colour for a second before it loops onto the next.

Instead of pausing for a second, I want to be able to loop through the colours individually by pressing enter at each colour. I believe I need to make use of a scanner to do this, but I cannot get it to work myself.

Any help and an explanation would be really appreciated.

Here's the code that I've used to create the current pause method and loop the colours:

```
  private void pause(long millisecs) {
    long startTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        while(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()-startTime<millisecs);
  } 


       public void flashColour()  { 

        Color [] rainbow = { Color.red,Color.orange,Color.yellow, Color.green,
                Color.blue,Color.magenta,Color.black };

        int index = 0;

        System.out.println("Start");
        pause(1000);

            while(index < rainbow.length) {             
                getContentPane().setBackground(rainbow[index]);
                pause(1000);

                index++;
            }               
        System.out.println("End");          
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood the purpose of a scanner. A scanner will parse primitive types and strings. What you're looking for is a keylistener. A keylistener will 'listen' for a specific key press (In this case enter) and run the appropriate code when that key is pressed.

For more information, see:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html